# Services file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote

In the services file I see open ports/ remote connections and streaming etc, Can someone connect to my pc from there?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: There are UDP and TCP's ports and the comment on the port says streaming, remote connection, tunneling, gateway etc, does that mean someone or someone federal can connect to my pc and remote view? etc

Comment: @Ramhound Comment above.

Comment: What about it?  Your question still isn't clear

Comment: @Ramhound What does this mean? in circled snag.gy/zIu7Dv.jpg

Comment: Can't access the image.  Upload to imgur and update your question

Comment: @Ramhound http://prnt.sc/f234a3

Comment: Still can't access the image.  Upload to **imgur** and include the link in your question.  *I can't view the image unless you do this.*

Comment: I see a lot from the OP that is fleshed out in comments.  Editing to include them in the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no sensitive information
in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services`,
so there’s no need to hide it. 
Here are the first 30 lines of the same file on my system:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2004 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This file contains port numbers for well-known services defined by IANA
#
# Format:
#
# <service name>  <port number>/<protocol>  [aliases...]   [#<comment>]
#

echo                7/tcp
echo                7/udp
discard             9/tcp    sink null
discard             9/udp    sink null
systat             11/tcp    users                  #Active users
systat             11/udp    users                  #Active users
daytime            13/tcp
daytime            13/udp
qotd               17/tcp    quote                  #Quote of the day
qotd               17/udp    quote                  #Quote of the day
chargen            19/tcp    ttytst source          #Character generator
chargen            19/udp    ttytst source          #Character generator
ftp-data           20/tcp                           #FTP, data
ftp                21/tcp                           #FTP. control
ssh                22/tcp                           #SSH Remote Login Protocol
telnet             23/tcp
smtp               25/tcp    mail                   #Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
time               37/tcp    timserver
time               37/udp    timserver
rlp                39/udp    resource               #Resource Location Protocol
nameserver         42/tcp    name                   #Host Name Server
```

If you look at the third line, you’ll see the key phrase: ***well-known***. 
These are standard, published parameters of how TCP/IP networking works. 
You can read about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

---

Secondly,

> Can someone connect to my PC from there?

Theoretically, yes. 
If you run an SSH server on your computer,
and you allow port 22 (the *well-known* SSH port)
to come through your firewall,
then people will be able to connect to your system via ssh. 
The same is true for an FTP server, a web server, an email server,
or any of the hundreds of other defined services. 
But these services are generally (a) disabled in the PC
and (b) blocked in the firewall, so you aren’t vulnerable
*unless you **make yourself vulnerable.***

Answer (score 1):

No. this file is only definition of map between port number and name. Just like DNS about the hostname and IPs. To enable service, described in the file you must run service/daemon